# Encoding Persian string using C#

Tags: c#, sms, farsi

I am developing an SMS application using **C#** for the bank which sends transaction alerts i.e. ATM transactions to the customer through the SMS gateway. The application is working fine, the only issue is encoding the Persian text, it doesn't encode the Persian text correctly.

Here is the method which encodes Persian text to UTF-16 format.

```
public static string Endian2UTF(string s)        
{

     Encoding ui = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode;              
     Encoding u8 = Encoding.UTF8;              
     string str = u8.GetString(ui.GetBytes(s));              
     return str;          
}
```

Some characters are not getting encoded correctly, the message on mobile device looks like as below

> مشترۯ뾽 ۯ뾽رامۯ뾽 شما به مقدار 500.00 افغانۯ뾽 از حساب خوب از ماشۯ뾽ن صرافۯ뾽 نماۯ뾽ندۯ뾽ۯ뾽 شهر نو بدست اوردۯ뾽د، تشۯ뾽ر از شما.

The issue is only with some characters as you see above.
For your information, there is no issue with the English string.

Comment: Input string is already in UTF-16. Show how you receive it. Can you load icoming data into `byte[]` instead of `string` and only then decode?

Comment: a `string` is a `string` is a `string` - encoding doesn't apply: that only applies when converting between `string` and bytes. So: whatever is happening here, it applies at the boundary between the `string` and bytes. What API are you using to send SMS? Presumably it applies there. You may need to specify a particular codepage or similar, but frankly: most APIs these days use UTF-8.

Comment: Dear @MarcGravell, Thank you for your reply. The API is accepting unicode string in below format ("\u0006E\u00064\u0006*\u00061\u0006�\0 \u0006�\u00061\u0006'\u0006E\u0006�"). The characters with ? mark indicates false encoding.

Comment: ahh. Your library already has functions to do the hex thing. Check the methods in the `Tools.cs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the issue. In the library somewhere the text was encoded incorrectly, so I traced it using debugger break point and found the root case. It was encoding the message to UTF8, once I changed it to BigEndianUnicode. It worked like a charm. Here is the code. You need to apply below changes in SendSms method in SMPPClient.cs file.

```
if (dataCoding == 8)
{
   //data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
     data = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(text);
}
else
{
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
}
```

One more changes you need to apply if still the SMS is sent as garbage. comment the part which encode the text to UTF in SMMPClient.cs

```
if (dataCoding == 8)
{
    //text = Tools.Endian2UTF(text);
      maxLength = 70;
}
```

I hope this could help anyone who use EasySMPP library to send SMS to client.