# Cannot print Arabic/Persian letters correctly in C#

Tags: c#, printing, printdocument

I have problems with printing typing Arabic letters in C# using printdocument.

Here's my code:

```cs
PrintDocument pd;
PaperSize ps;

void pd_Factor(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Font vazir = new Font("Vazir Code FD", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    string a = "سلام";
    g.DrawString(a, vazir, sb, 200, 330);
}

private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    PaperSize ps = new PaperSize("Factor", 723, 1024);
    pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_Factor);
    pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0;
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0;
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0;
    pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0;

    pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
    printDialog1.Document = pd;
    if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Sadly, the above code prints this way:
[image]

By the way, I tried

```cs
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
g.DrawString(a, vazir, sb, 200, 330, format);
```

It just make the position of anchor going from up-left to up-right this way:
[image]

So, I thought with myself, I should reverse it:

```cs
string a = "سلام";
string b = "";
for (int i = a.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
{
    b += Convert.ToString(a[i]);
}
```

And it made the text looks like this:
[image]

It still looks wrong but it goes better.

However I tried adding characters from left-to-right using character map.

And my code changed to:

```cs
string a = "ﻡﺎﻠﺳ";
```

And it prints correctly:
[image]

By the way, I have an input and I don't know what is the text going to be; so, I can't use character map for that.

Also it looks impossible or hard to code to replace the text; at least I need these characters:
[image]

My question is: How to print correctly?

Note: The font I'm using is [this](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-code-font); However I tried using Tahoma too, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encoding Persian string using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62621119/encoding-persian-string-using-c-sharp)

Comment: It's problem is with encoding, I have problem with direction

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219654/c-sharp-print-right-to-left#comment39281362_25219654?

Comment: nope i tried searching

Comment: The problem is that I use exactly the same code but It prints reverse

Comment: Maybe using web browser and javascript can be a workaround? But it isn't a solution

Comment: Did you actually read the comment? Have you tried specifying a rectangle and adding `\u200f` as suggested?

Comment: What print driver are you using? Is it s PCL or PS driver?  Make sure you are using a PS driver since you are using PS fonts.

Comment: GSerg Sorry for misunderstanding but his problem is that the anchors are in the top-right not top-left btw I'll try it and I'll report that

Comment: jdweng I don't know what they are; I just used Microsoft XPS for testing

Comment: GSerg Adding \u200f didn't work; Maybe It's a PCL driver (as jdweng mentioned) and that caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange, But magically Problem Solved!

I tried using another app to test called "Print2Pdf" and the text prints correctly, Maybe it's a bug of Microsoft XPS writer/reader that cannot print/read Arabic/Persian letters.

*Sorry for not providing link to Print2Pdf as I couldn't find the original website; If someone knows the original please add link; Thanks